# Open another application from your own (intent)

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to update my own programs, and I know how to open programs using the a predefined Uri (for sms or email for example)

I need to know how I can create an Intent to open MyTracks or any other application that I don't know what intents they listen to.

I got this info from DDMS, but I havn't been succesful in turning this to an Intent I can use. This is taken from when opening MyTracks manually.

Thanks for your help

```
05-06 11:22:24.945: INFO/ActivityManager(76): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks bnds=[243,338][317,417] }
05-06 11:22:25.005: INFO/ActivityManager(76): Start proc com.google.android.maps.mytracks for activity com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks: pid=1176 uid=10063 gids={3003, 1015}
05-06 11:22:26.995: INFO/ActivityManager(76): Displayed activity com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks: 1996 ms (total 1996 ms)
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Firstly, the concept of "application" in Android is slightly an extended one.

An application - technically a process - can have multiple activities, services, content providers and/or broadcast listeners. If at least one of them is running, the application is up and running (the process).

So, what you have to identify is how do you want to "start the application".

Ok... here's what you can try out:

1. Create an intent with `action=MAIN` and `category=LAUNCHER`
2. Get the `PackageManager` from the current context using `context.getPackageManager`
3. `packageManager.queryIntentActivity(<intent>, 0)` where intent has `category=LAUNCHER`, `action=MAIN` or `packageManager.resolveActivity(<intent>, 0)` to get the first activity with main/launcher
4. Get the`ActivityInfo` you're interested in
5. From the `ActivityInfo`, get the `packageName` and `name`
6. Finally, create another intent with with `category=LAUNCHER`, `action=MAIN`, `componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name)` and `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`
7. Finally, `context.startActivity(newIntent)`

Comment: What If i wanted to open three separate apps?

Comment: The community wiki answer below is better, if you know the package name http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596063/379115

Comment: How can you pass data between the calling app and the launched app? I've found 'Intent.putExtra()' but I don't know how to retrieve the extra data in the launched app.

Comment: `onCreate` => `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras()` => `if(extras != null) { extras.getString("blah") }` etc

Comment: `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage()` already does all that for you  https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#L137

Comment: what about if you wanna resume this app from background not launch it again

Comment: That's not under your control. That's defined by the activity's manifest - singleTop, singleInstance etc.

Comment: You saved my life! It's worked on android 4.x, 5, 7. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 245):

I have work it like this,

```
/** Open another app.
 * @param context current Context, like Activity, App, or Service
 * @param packageName the full package name of the app to open
 * @return true if likely successful, false if unsuccessful
 */
public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null) {
            return false;
            //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
openApp(this, "com.google.android.maps.mytracks");
```

Comment: because getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name") may cause exception.

Comment: This is a great answer, simple catch the exception and do what you need, notify user etc

Comment: Not to be a stickler, but there's no reason to allocate a new Intent on the first line given you use the result of the `getLaunchIntentForPackage` call.

Comment: `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`already adds the category, see source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java#L150

Comment: The only problem for me is `Context` object where/how to get/create it?And what packages to import. New in Java for Android development.

Answer (score 97):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks"));
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT :**

as suggested in comments, add one line before `startActivity(intent);`

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: but it requires to know the name of the activity

Comment: I tried this and got an error recommending to use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. I added this line before startActivity and it worked: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: @njzk2 finding the package name for something on Google Play is easy; it is right there in the URL. For example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en

Comment: @iceybobby yes the package name is easy to find, but how do you find the class name of the activity to launch?

Comment: @phreakhead You're right. I think I used the solution in this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/8944286/1224186 so the activity name wasn't needed, and so I think that makes my reply to njzk2 unhelpful here.

Answer (score 40):

If you already have the package name you wish to activate, you can use the following code which is a bit more generic:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName);
if (null != appStartIntent)
{
    context.startActivity(appStartIntent);
}
```

I found that it works better for cases where the main activity was not found by the regular method of start the MAIN activity.

Comment: Best Answer for me :-) helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: It is perfect for me. Thank you very much Muzikant : )

Answer (score 13):

This is the code of my solution base on MasterGaurav solution:

```
private void  launchComponent(String packageName, String name){
    Intent launch_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    launch_intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    launch_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
    launch_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    activity.startActivity(launch_intent);
}

public void startApplication(String application_name){
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveinfo_list = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for(ResolveInfo info:resolveinfo_list){
            if(info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(application_name)){
                launchComponent(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "There was a problem loading the application: "+application_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using the solution from inversus, I expanded the snippet with a function, that will be called when the desired application is not installed at the moment. So it works like: *Run application by package name. If not found, open Android market - Google play for this package*.

```
public void startApplication(String packageName)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for(ResolveInfo info : resolveInfoList)
            if(info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageName))
            {
                launchComponent(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                return;
            }

        // No match, so application is not installed
        showInMarket(packageName);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        showInMarket(packageName);
    }
}

private void launchComponent(String packageName, String name)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    startActivity(intent);
}

private void showInMarket(String packageName)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
startApplication("org.teepee.bazant");
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this :

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have any idea ? open an test.apk instead of installed in device store in inside existing application.  hints when click a button lunch test.apk apps that was stored in existing project.   thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 6):

Open application if it is exist, or open Play Store application for install it:

```
private void open() {
    openApplication(getActivity(), "com.app.package.here");
}

public void openApplication(Context context, String packageN) {
    Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageN);
    if (i != null) {
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageN)));
        }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageN)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should be  if (i != null)

Answer (score 4):

To Start another application activity from my application Activity. It is working fine for me.

**Below code will work if the another application already installed in your phone otherwise it is not possible to redirect form one app to another app.So make sure your app launched or not**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.xyz.myapplication", "com.xyz.myapplication.SplashScreenActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please do not write multiple answers that are almost identical to the same question. Use the "edit" link below the answer and change the original.

Answer (score 3):

// This works on Android Lollipop 5.0.2

```
public static boolean launchApp(Context context, String packageName) {

    final PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent appLauncherIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    appLauncherIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = manager.queryIntentActivities(appLauncherIntent, 0);
    if ((null != resolveInfos) && (!resolveInfos.isEmpty())) {
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : resolveInfos) {
            String className = rInfo.activityInfo.name.trim();
            String targetPackageName = rInfo.activityInfo.packageName.trim();
            Log.d("AppsLauncher", "Class Name = " + className + " Target Package Name = " + targetPackageName + " Package Name = " + packageName);
            if (packageName.trim().equals(targetPackageName)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName(targetPackageName, className);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("AppsLauncher", "Launching Package '" + packageName + "' with Activity '" + className + "'");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open another application and it is not installed you can send it to the Google App Store to download

1. First create the openOtherApp method for example

   ```
   public static boolean openOtherApp(Context context, String packageName) {
       PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
           Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
           if (intent == null) {
               //the app is not installed
               try {
                   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
                   context.startActivity(intent);
               } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                   //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
                   return false;
               }

            }
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```

2.- Usage

```
openOtherApp(getApplicationContext(), "com.packageappname");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since applications aren't allowed to change many of the phone settings, you can open a settings activity just like another application.

Look at you LogCat output after you actually modified the setting manually:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(1306): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings } from pid 1924
```

Then use this to display the settings page from your app:

```
String SettingsPage = "com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings";

try
{
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);             
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(SettingsPage));             
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );             
startActivity(intent); 
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
 log it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For API level 3+, nothing more then one line of code:

`Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("name.of.package");`

Return a CATEGORY_INFO launch Intent (apps with no launcher activity, wallpapers for example, often use this to provide some information about app) and, if no find it, returns the CATEGORY_LAUNCH of package, if exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you're attempting to start a SERVICE rather than activity, this worked for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.otherapplication", "com.example.otherapplication.ServiceName");
context.startService(intent);
```

If you use the intent.setComponent(...) method as mentioned in other answers, you may get an "Implicit intents with startService are not safe" warning.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also open the intent from your app in the other app with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

where `uri` is the deeplink to the other app

Answer (score 2):

Use following:

```
String packagename = "com.example.app";
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packagename));
```

Answer (score 2):

## Launch an application from another application on Android

```
  Intent launchIntent = getActivity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ionicframework.uengage");
        startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, Hope this will help you. If this package is available then this will open the app or else open the play store for downloads

```
    String  packageN = "aman4india.com.pincodedirectory";

            Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageN);
            if (i != null) {
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageN)));
                }
                catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageN)));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to find the package names installed on a device:

```
adb shell pm list packages -3 -f
```

Reference: http://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-determine-the-package-name-of-an-android-app/

Answer (score -3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package_name","package_name.class_name"));
        intent.putExtra("grace", "Hi");
        startActivity(intent);
```