# Can I use Google Places intent in my app?

Tags: android, google-api

I have an app that shows a map with markers for addresses near the user.  I'd like to be able to open the address marker in the Google Places app when the user taps a marker.  I'm not sure if Places is open enough for others to use at will.

Currently I'm just using the search api to get directions to the address.  Not the most elegant solution :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to open the Google Places activity by using intents. But I don't know how to specify an address as data argument. Actually, you can open any App in Android by intents. To find out the information about the activity string you can read from the Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS), e.g. by using LogCat in Eclipse.

An example about how to start the activity, have a look at [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Answer (score 0):

You can most often access any intent installed on the device, in the same fashion as you access your own intents. The difference is the namespace qualification that needs to be added.

On Google Play you can download a free app called ManifestViewer to show installed intents and their full namespaces. This tool can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.susatthi.ManifestViewer)

Of course, you need to know if the intent needs to be invoked in a special way or if it requires some input attached.