# Android - passing callback from activity to service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a situation where an activity needs to start 2 services, one is bound, one is not.

The bound will return a Ibinder to the activity. But the activity needs to some how provide a callback to both the services, i.e. both services must be able to call some methods in a nested class in the activity.

What is the best way to do this ? Should I use broadcast from services, and then call the desired API from the onReceive() ? Or can I pass a IBinder from my activity to service in the intent, and the service could use it to make a IPC call back ?

**Edit**

Forgot to clarify .. the two services are in a different app than the activity.

Answer (score 2):

you could to use `LocalBroadcastManager` Sending An `Intent` for `Activity`

I believe it is the best option for this scenario **EventBus** or **Otto**

> EventBus is an Android optimized publish/subscribe event bus. A
>   typical use case for Android apps is gluing Activities, Fragments, and
>   background threads together. Conventional wiring of those elements
>   often introduces complex and error-prone dependencies and life cycle
>   issues. With EventBus propagating listeners through all participants
>   (e.g. background service -> activity -> multiple fragments or helper
>   classes) becomes deprecated. EventBus decouples event senders and
>   receivers and thus simplifies communication between app components.
>   Less code, better quality. And you don't need to implement a single
>   interface!

Comment: What if the two services were in a different app ? (I didn't clearly state that in the question)

Comment: @Jake, Yes, it was not clear! See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876319/using-intents-as-a-form-of-message-passing/24876668#24876668