# Launching activity after call end interface Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a call receiver with `abstract class`, by receiving call start recording of call and on call end stoping the recording, this flow is working perfect. What makes it difficult is after call ends, I want to open my form which is also working but it is creating problem some time that intent is not launching, is some one help me out whats going wrong that my `activity` is not opening some times. Using following code to launch the `activity`.

```
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent();
    dialogIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    dialogIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    dialogIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, CustomerEntery.class);
    dialogIntent.setComponent(cn);
    context.startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: getting any error ?

Comment: no not any error, but some time my form is not opening.

Comment: please debug first and check.

Comment: when i debug its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Replace your component line with this :

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("The package name of the activity that you wish to launch","Its fully qualified class name");
```

Like

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(“com.android.settings”, “com.android.settings.fuelgauge.CustomerEntery”)
```

Just giving a try, hope this helps !

EDIT : Another way to achieve the same :

```
public boolean openActivity(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
      Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
      if (i == null) {
        return false;
        //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
      }
      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
      context.startActivity(i);
      return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Then :

```
openActivity(this, “com.android.settings.fuelgauge.CustomerEntery”);
```

Comment: sorry thats creating exception Run time, activity not found

Comment: Are you setting the right name ? I am able to launch activity with same on my end. Point is it should not throw "activity not found" maybe some other exception, can you check your package name once ! And the activity is in manifest right .The answer source was [this](https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/6829505)

Comment: yes true i was doing some thing wrong.. thanks for help its works like charm !

Comment: No problem, glad it helped !

Comment: @JhamanDas : Can you tell me why it is not working ? Is there an exception ?

Comment: there is no exception some its working, some time not, getting this issue in few mobiles

Comment: could you please help me out regarding this matter

Comment: @JhamanDas : I found another way , can you check now , hope this one would work !