# How to launch third-party games from my application on android?

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

I want to create an application that will launch multiple games installed on my android device. And user should be able to switch between different games.

Basically I want a look like fragments in which there is a sidebar containing the names of different games and upon clicking the names of the game, that game should start.

Presently I am getting a security exception that my application is requesting code from other application.

Any help appreciated.

Edit: Can this be achieved if i have root access on my device?

Comment: Why you want to achieve this? What is the purpose of having all app icon on screen? BTW see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow: I want to create an interactive application that would allow users to play different games from within my application.

Comment: That's not how Android works. You can't write a wrapper around other people's apps. You can launch an app that's installed on the device, but then you lose control over what happens afterwards.

Comment: Can this be achieved if i have root access on my device?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please refer the links to achieve it.
http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/launching-different-applications-from-android-activity-using-intent/

[Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes this is quite possible. But the problem is as i do startactivity, i lose the view of my application, due to which i am not able to start another game from my application if i want.

Comment: That's correct... once you launch another application, your application is not coming back until the user hits the back button or relaunches your app.

Comment: Make an System wide variable which set to true and false while exiting third party app to go back and restarting your app :) (sarcasm/>

Comment: Can this be achieved if i have root access on my device?