# Android: Intent to open root explorer

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm looking for the intent of a Root Explorer (e.g. Super Manager, Root Explorer...) I just want to create a button that opens this explorer. 
I found the intent of OI Filemanager but this has no root function.

Comment: Contact the developers at support@speedsoftware.co.uk and ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Here is one of the ways:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    startActivity(intent);
```

That link above should have all the info you need, though.

Of course, this method doesn't open the file explorer specifically. You would have to change the package name appropriately.

Comment: Thx for your help :)
I know now how it works

Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("gpc.myweb.hinet.net.TaskManager");
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this 

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"));
startActivity(intent);
```