# Can an app resident on Google TV determine what other apps are resident on the platform

Tags: android, google-tv

Hello I'm looking for some insight as to how an application I create and install on Google TV can determine what other apps are on the platform.  If my app determines what other apps are on the box can my app launch them? Can my app be instructed to launch them via anymot protocols?

Answer (score 2):

> Can an app resident on Google TV determine what other apps are resident on the platform

If this is a standard Android app, you can use the standard Android [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) to identify what else is on the device, whether that is a phone, tablet, or Google TV.

> If my app determines what other apps are on the box can my app launch them?

Use `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` to get an `Intent` suitable for use with `startActivity()` to launch a particular package.

> Can my app be instructed to launch them via anymot protocols?

I have no idea on that one, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

See [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent) on how to get the intent to launch an app. For Anymote you need to convert the intent to a uri string with intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME). Then use the Anymote fling message with that uri to start the app on the Google TV device. See the Able Remote app for how this works.