# Worklight - Open a Native application

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

In Worklight, its possible to open a native page from the Worklight application for Android. Is it possible to launch a native application from an application developed by Worklight in an Android device? If possible, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and it has nothing to do with Worklight :)
In your native page in Worklight (or you can write a phonegap plugin if you prefer), you need to create an intent (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).
This intent can open an external application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. 
Here is a training that explains how to open native activity from Worklight application - http://worklight.com/download/get-started/4.2.1/module-9.1

If you want to open another activity (other app) from your application, you will need to create a PhoneGap plugin which creates an Intent object to open a new application.

This question may contain what you're looking for [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

And here you can see how to implement PhoneGap plugin for Android - http://worklight.com/download/get-started/4.2.1/module-9.3

Answer (score 2):

IBM Worklight has samples that cover calling the native app, but that was created in worklight itself. Eg: `module_09_1_Android_CombiningNativeAndWebPages` in this sample in the Android folder itself they created one activity `com.AndroidShowNativePage.HelloNative` (package name) that activity was invoking from that JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Using Worklight you can call native page ,

code:

WL.Nativepage.show("com.example.class",backtopage,parameter);

function backtopage()

custom parameter to call native code and back to web page.

if you have doubt please refer "Anton" link .