# [Android]action another app

Tags: android, android-intent

I use Htc's phone.
My phone's lock screen can show the icons which are added in my main screen's bottom bar.
The bar allow me add app and shortcut.
If I type the password to unlock my phone,it took me 10 second.
So I have a thinking:

I write a app to create a shortcut and the shortcut can broadcast to the record app to start record.

`{
    Intent shortCutContain =new Intent("example.app.REC");
    shortCutContain.setClassName("example.app",  "example.app.AudioService");
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT,shortCutContain);
}`

this is what I do......but it failed

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to start the recorder:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(requestCode == RQS_RECORDING){
savedUri = data.getData();
Toast.makeText(AndroidIntentAudioRecording.this,"Saved: " + savedUri.getPath(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Put this code on your `onCreate()` if you want to launch the recorder automatically.

Comment: thanks your answer.
But the record app I am using which can save to many format.
So I want to send the action to record app.

Comment: You want to launch a 3rd app. check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: The record app can add a widget on main screen.The widget send PendingIntent to AudioService to record without open activity.But the post or example articles only told me how to "startActivity".