# Open other applications from my application in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know how can i make my app as a launcher to start other apps.(Not written by me)

For example i want to open games like

1) Angry Birds
2) Basketball shoot

etc

from my app on click of button for each game. 
How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out thoose games package, and start them via an `Intent`. Like this:

```
String packageName = "com.rovio.angrybirds";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use intent. Please look at the following link. It answers your question in detailed way.
[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)