# How to start an Intent from a ResolveInfo

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

I'm trying to make a custom launcher for android, and I'm trying to figure out how to launch a different application form mine.  I figured the way to do it was intents, and I've found a post on it here:

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

I don't really understand the answer though!  Can someone give me a concise snippet or series of steps to go from a single ResolveInfo to launching the app represented by that ResolveInfo?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Given a `ResolveInfo` named `launchable`:

```
ActivityInfo activity=launchable.activityInfo;
ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                     activity.name);
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);

startActivity(i);
```

(from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot)

Comment: everything is ok but every app has deffrent icon size that here is not managed

Answer (score 22):

Create an new Intent by this way.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
            resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: could the 2nd line be shorter?    intent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
            resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);