# Can an Android app open another Android app?

Tags: android, launch

Is it possible to create an Android App that will launch another Android App and close itself when openned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been already asked and answered on StackOverflow:

[How to launch an Activity from another Application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

In short, **Intent** is the keyword of what you are looking for.

Comment: That is true, I must admit I have asked this one without proper research (it was an extension of another one I have properly researched, I honestly forgot).

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible. Have a look at `Intent`. You can close your activity with `finish()`.