# Start another app using Intents and Intent filters

Tags: android

So what I am is pretty simple, but I can't figure it out.  I am trying to start another app using an intent and intent filter.

In my first app when a user clicks on a button I want it to start another activity in a separate app. This is the intent I am using in the first app with the button.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("foo");
```

In my second app I am trying to catch that intent by defining an Intent filter in the manifest like this:

```
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app" >
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <action android:name="foo" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Shouldn't the MainActivity catch the intent and start up?  It doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to open new app from your app then you have to provide package name to start

Hear is an example code

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("your package name");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);`
```

`

Answer (score -1):

To start new application with intent you provide entire package name with activity name. Refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent) in that you can find the same.

Comment: I know how to do it using the package name, but I do not want to do it that way. I want to have a custom action name that will start the activity.

Comment: You refer link which i give you?

Comment: Yes I did. None of those answers solves my problem. They require the name of the package.