# Android Instagram

Tags: android

please help! I want share my photo into Instagram. I use Intent for sharing, but I don't need at all list in Share, such as - Facebook, Instagram, Gmail, Bluetoth... etc. I need only Instagram. I want share photo into Instagram by only onclickListener. How can do it? thanks.

Comment: Call Instagram package name into intent directly so it will not display share via dialog.

Comment: Please show me code, how can call package of instagram, because I don't found this. I do like this:                                      `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("image/jpeg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Path/To/Image.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));`

Comment: You can set package name when you create an intent. Remember to put your intent in an try catch clause in case the target user doesn't have instagram app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is asked a long time ago. But the clear answer is not here. That's why, I want to answer as well.

I have been used that code below and it worked. It redirects to crop screen of instagram directly. (Of course, Instagram app must be installed on the device.)

```
...
Intent intent = createInstagramIntent("file://" + filePath);
startActivity(intent);
...
```

and

```
private Intent createInstagramIntent(String uriString) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uriString));
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add checks if instagram is installed? (by PackageManager) otherwise it may crash.

Comment: But after the Sharing is done, will the Instagram app redirect the user back to our App?

Answer (score -2):

Create your custom sharing screen that call instagram.

Comment: Please show me sample code, how can call package of instagram, because I don't found this. I do like this: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); i.setType("image/jpeg"); i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Path/To/Image.jpg")); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));`

Comment: Create dialog view with instagram button. See this article:http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2011/10/appchooser.html

Comment: But I don't need dialog with choose. I need by click on ImageButton post Image to app insragram

Comment: send intent with package name of instagram application(com.instagram.android). See this post how do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: com.instagram.android - NotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.instagram.android }. I have tried this issue

Comment: see your the package name of your instagramm app from package manager.Have you install intagram app to your phone?

Comment: Yes I have instll instagram, but don't get any information about Instagram package

Comment: I have 9 reputation - I can't use chat in this site. maybe skype? I have information througth PackageManager that Instagram on my phone is - com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity. but if i use this package I have classNotfoundexception.

Comment: I have tried `final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  final List pkgAppsList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);`