# Android Call Instagram package name into Intent directly

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177677/android-instagram)

Please give me example calling app package of Instagram in Intent android. Thanks.
com.instagram.android  - not work
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent