# How to call an apk from another app without having its source code

Tags: android

I am developing a app in which i want to call another app apk but i don't have the code of that app so i don't know the package name and class name.i have searched alot but couldn't find anything that works. does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think this is not possible you can call already installed application from your application.

Comment: run the app, read the logcat, find the component name in it

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly possible. You don't need to know its "source code", you need to do a bit of research on the app and you're probably going to find its package's name.

You can:

- a) Try to de-pack the .apk which is extremely tedious (or was last time I tried)
- b) Write a    very simple app that will list all of your installed apps (by package name)
- c) Some custom and even stock firmwares even have that option baked in when you go to Apps/Installed/All or something similar to that.

Once you have the package name. For example, com.adobe.reader for...well...Adobe Reader, then you can launch the app really simply by using an Intent.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

For a similar, but maybe clearer for you view of things, you can check out this link:

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Comment: Where to put the apk file after getting the package name?

Comment: To launch it, the app needs to be installed.