# Open external Android app from within MGWT (gwt-phonegap) app

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, mgwt

I'm trying to find out how I can launch a native Android app inside a MGWT app (wrapped into a native Android app with PhoneGap) by clicking on a button (for example).

I've followed the [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent) and it works great using this code snippet:

```
Button openAppButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openApp);
openAppButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // THIS WORKS GREAT         
            Intent i = new Intent();
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("ch.android.test2");
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

So basically if I click the button in app1 it opens the native app with namespace "ch.android.test2".

The difference is though that this works just launching a native Android app from within another native Android app. What I need is the same functionality from a PhoneGap app made with MGWT.

How would I have to accomplish this?
Thanks for suggestions in advance.

Comment: Wrap this code in a plugin. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With phonegap you can write any native code, so you need to move the code you pointed out into a phonegap plugin as Simon pointed out, see: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

After that you need to call your plugin from GWT source code by using JSNI. Take a look at the ChildBrowser implementation in gwt-phonegap: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/gwtphonegap/client/plugins/childbrowser/ChildBrowserPhoneGapImpl.java

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That seems to be exactly what I was looking for.