# Android Barcode Scanner - Automatically choose scanner

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I have integrated ZXING barcode scanner in my app.

How can stop my app for asking different scanner apps(based on zxing) 
and automatically choose my app for scanning ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: didn't help :(
can it be specific to scanner please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IntentIntegrator`, which will automatically choose the official Barcode Scanner app by restricting the packages searched.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java