# Start another app from my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, vlc

I want to start the wondershare player from my current activity and to make it (the wondershare player) use some passed argument (throught the call) as a streaming url.

I found some example using VLC instead of wondershare at https://github.com/rauljim/tgs-android/blob/integrate_record/src/com/tudelft/triblerdroid/first/VideoPlayerActivity.java#L211
but I couldn't deploy it in my case.

I appreciate your help.

B.R

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this Stack Overflow post with a detailed explanation on launching activities from other apps:

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Comment: is there a way to catch the event of the new started applciation ? and I'm getting an ugly message on the screen talking about " buffering the data in order to play it ", is there a way to make hide it ? Thanks

Comment: You can capture results from the activity that you launch, but it is very dependant on how that other app's activity was implemented, and whether it returns a result or not, etc. Try reading this guide, it might help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: the new activity is a media content player so, I don't think it's going to return any value or data . Instead, I want to handle its events from within my activity ( if it's possible ) and how can I close the started player when I'm back to my activity ? I appreciate your help

Comment: As far as I know once you launch another intent it has control, unless it's meant to pass on data/callbacks to the original intent. I'm not familiar with media content player specifically. I'm sorry I can't be of any more help, but perhaps this link will be helpful, it's all about the android media player: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: And this guide might be helpful: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.tudelft.triblerdroid.first");
//put your extras here into Intent
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```