# Starting an installed app from my app

Tags: android, installed-applications

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            //String s1 = ?
    Intent i = new Intent();
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

EDIT:I saw that if we write the app package name in place of packageName in quotes then it opens that app.
I mean

```
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.mms");
```

instead of

```
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

So I wan define a string s that will get the package name of the app that is selected based on the position. How can I do that?

This isnt a duplicate cuz I have tried all that. I just wanna know how to edit the above code and get what I want.

Comment: Where do you set the packageName, packageName should be the package name of other apps.

Comment: Your `packageName` does not appear to be dependent upon what the user clicks in the list.

Comment: How can I do that dependable?

Comment: I get packageName from another activity. Currently it shows like com.android.mms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: I have tried all the options on that. I think it opens settings cuz thats the first app in the list.

Comment: I have edited the code @CommonsWare. Please tell me what I can do. It would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the position parameter  , which return the item that was clicked. If packageName is an ArrayList with all the packageNames in it, try packageName.get(position)

Comment: Could you please show in the above code where I need to write that?

Comment: What is the variable packageName?

Comment: packageName = list.get(position).activityInfo.packageName;

Comment: Got my answer

Its String selectedFromList = (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));