# Deep link of android application

Tags: android, google-play

I had an application in Store, and I need to put a deep link for it.

my problem is the link not opening the application, it just gives me the page of my application in the store, if not installed the page of store gives me the option to **install**, and if the app is installed the store gives me **open** or **uninstall**.

**What I need is: opening the application automatically if installed whithout passing by the store.**

Comment: may be you want this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937677/how-to-open-a-installed-android-app-with-a-button-click-intent

Comment: I had this issue before, had to remove the deep link code block.

Comment: @Kyle can you explain more ?

Comment: @milapTank, thank's but it's not the same as me.

Comment: @Euphor08 I removed the blocks stated here: http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: Yes i tried this link, and **Test Your Deep Links** works fine but when I test the deep link in the navigator it opens the play store, not the app :/

Comment: give your package name.

Comment: my PK name : com.paperpad.casadelmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I had to add this code into my Android manifest in my falvors too.

```
 <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://” -->
               <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:pathPrefix="/casa" />
```

and the commadn in terminal is :

```
$ adb shell am start  -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://example/casa" com.paperpad.casadelmar
```

Comment: yes, I had 2 manifest, the first for the app and the second for the flavor. I add it only in one, so that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:hope it may helps

```
Intent launchIntent=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("yourPackagename");
if (launchIntent == null) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(" Playstore your APP link")));
  } else {
           startActivity(launchIntent);
         }
```

Comment: thank's, but I need a deep link, not a programmatically solution