# Open my second app on button click in first app

Tags: java, android

how to add a project using library in another project.
I've created 2 individual apps and now just wanted to add my second app into the first one in a way that the output should be like this:
if i click a button from first app it will run my second app.

Comment: @Rasima, this might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288440/how-to-create-a-java-application-which-can-be-run-by-a-click

Comment: I googled "open an app on button click android" and the first result was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937677/how-to-open-a-installed-android-app-with-a-button-click-intent

Comment: This is not about adding a library but to open an app on button click

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343531/2633909

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any library to do that just put this code on your first app button click and add package name of your second app which you want to open, you will found that in the manifest file at the top like this "com.package.address".

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
  try{
    startActivity(launchIntent);
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```