# Access control from another application in Android

Tags: android

there is two app. App A is writen by others,App B is writen by me,Is there any way to access control(Example Button Control)of App A  from App B? sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with 3rd Apps by using Intents:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

You have more info here: [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Comment: Thansks for your answer,Is is a way of Open another application.Can I access  the control of the Launch app.(For Example TextBlock of the Activity).