# Launch a specific activity from an application

Tags: android, android-activity, launch, android-launcher

Just a little problem:

For example I have the activity `TestActivity` in my Application `com.example.testapp`
but the activity doesn't have the flag `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

now my question is how can i check if a given activity `subpackage.SomeActivity`
exists in a Package `com.test.somepackage`

it would be the same as typing in a console:

```
adb shell am start -n com.test.somepackage/subpackage.SomeActivity
```

and if it exists, how can i launch it from another app?

***××××× to clarify my question ×××××***

i am searching for functions in android like
`Intent startthis = new Intent (packagename, activityname);`

and if its possible something like
`ActivityInfo[] ai = fetchAllActivitysFromPackage(packagename);`

is there any function in android that does likely the same?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent) solves your problem?

Comment: @hichris123 i need it because i want to have a list with all installed apps and all directly callable activitys (there is no better reason)

Comment: Then you could use a PackageManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int).

Comment: i got so far already. my last problem is how can i choose an activity to start if i know the package name? something like `new Intent (packagename, activityname)`
and if its possible something like `ActivityInfo[] ai = fetchAllActivitysFromPackage(packagename)` those functions i search for
or anything that does the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all activities for packages the following way:

```
List<PackageInfo> installedPackages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
Iterator packageIterator = installedPackages.iterator();
PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
while(packageIterator.hasNext()){
    packageInfo = (PackageInfo) packageIterator.next();
    if(packageInfo.activities != null){
        for(ActivityInfo activity : packageInfo.activities){
            Log.d("ACTIVITY", activity.name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, you can only start an external activity if that app has defined an intent-filter for it, and if you now the exact ACTION of the intent filter.

**Update:**
To get all activities for one package name, use:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

Comment: thanks that works like a charm for my first question, thanks!
i found out myself how to start one of the activitys later:
`Intent intent = new Intent();`
`intent.setClassName("com.test.packagename", ".Activity");`
`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`
`context.startActivity(intent);`