# Loading Existing Android App in mobile by clicking button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, native

I have developed a small Android app by using jquery mobile. In that jquery mobile app i am using a button to open my another native android  app. Is it possible if i click on jquery mobile app button to load/open native android app which is already install in mobile and working fine ?

Please help me to provide any script for this. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code you have so far and explain what about it isn't working. Your question is too vague to likely get a good answer otherwise.

Comment: Ok let me explain again that I have an Android app developed in Jquery mobile Which has some image buttons. I want to be able to touch the button and it launch a native mobile App, which is already installed. Lets say if i clicked on the button it should open the Skype app. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Link : [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)