# How to run a method from another class? java - android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Basically i want to call a method from another class. I want the `data()` method from `DownloadXML.java` to be called in `MainActivity.java`

It is an android application

so here is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String item;       

    DownloadXML a = new DownloadXML();
    a.data(); 
    // SYNTAX ERROR ON TOKEN "DATA" IDENTIFIER EXPECTED AFTER THIS TOKEN

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            item = getItemFromXML(this);
        }catch (XmlPullParserException e){
        }catch (IOException e){
        }

        String[] items = item.split("\n");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    }

    public String getItemFromXML(Activity activity) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Resources res = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.items);
        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                if (xpp.getName().equals("Item")){

                    stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "Event") + "\n");
                }
                if (xpp.getName().equals("ab")){

                    stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "when") + "\n");
                }
                if (xpp.getName().equals("cd")){

                    stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "where") + "\n" + "----------------------------------------------" + "\n");
                }



            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();

    }

}
```

Here is the DownloadXML.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class DownloadXML {

    DownloadXML(){

    }

    public void data() throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/lab/lab.xml");
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
          (new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\eyas\\workspace\\CebuHQ\\res\\xml\\items.xml"));
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
             writer.write(line);
             writer.newLine();
          }
          reader.close();
          writer.close();
    }

}
```

When i tried to instantiate it and call the method it has an error of:

```
DownloadXML a = new DownloadXML();
a.data(); SYNTAX ERROR ON TOKEN "DATA" IDENTIFIER EXPECTED AFTER THIS TOKEN
```

Can you guys help me with this. Thanks

Comment: First you need a try and catch around `a.data()` because it throws an exception ;)

Comment: Move it to onCreate  `a.data()`

Comment: You cannot call a method from inside the class alone, it has to be in another method of that class.

Comment: tried it on the onCreate method there is this error Unhandled exception type Exception

Comment: is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only code that can go outside a method is variable declarations and initializations. If you want to call a method you have to do it inside a method or constructor.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String item;

    DownloadXML a = new DownloadXML();
    a.data(); //This won't work. Put it inside a method

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
    }
```

Please try something like this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

            String item; 

           @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                //...
                DownloadXML a = new DownloadXML();
                a.data(); 
            }
}
```

Comment: Your method throws an exception. Probably because the file path does not exists on an Android device. This is another issue and is not related to your first problem.

Comment: You need to add a try and catch around `a.data()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public class DownloadXML {

     public static void data(){
        // Do whatever you want
     }
 }
```

and call it like this:

```
 DownloadXML.data();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a class of another package you will need to relatively code into each package [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)s. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent) describes the overall task of how that is done. Essentially one package must be willing to accept whatever the other package flags for it. You should also look up [Interprocess Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). The reason for this is because Android uses Java's "[Sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29)" concept. I hope I understood your problem correctly...