# Starting Unity program through Android notification using intent

Tags: c#, android, mobile, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am creating a mobile software that combines Unity and Android.  The user interface is created by Unity and Android is used to access native functionality.

Does anyone have an idea how can I start the Unity program through Intent?  I need this to start the application if the user receives a notification from server.  The notifications work properly, but I have problem starting the Unity program when the user clicks on a notification.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent/7596063

Answer (score 0):

Use the checkbox "google android project" when building. You will have a project with a single activity in the manifest, by default it has main and launcher intents. Add your activities and intents to this project.

Also, won't [plugins](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) work for you better?