# How to launch (programmatically) an Android app by an new Eclipse plugin deployed on ADT eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, adt

Is it possible to launch a specific Android app (e.g. a simple helloworld app), 
through a new plugin (Developed with Eclipse Standard Ver: Luna Release (4.4.0)) deployed under Eclipse ADT?

Trying with the following code in the plugin:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
```

startActivity(LaunchIntent);

There is the following error in an Information Dialog:

> The chosen operation is not currently available.

What is the correct procedure?

Comment: Are you writing the correct package name instead of `com.package.address` ?

Comment: I use "com.example.testhello", that is the package of  android app example used in ADT workspace.

Comment: I also followed the next post ... but the error is always the same
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent