# How to share link via twitter in android?

Tags: android, twitter

In my app I need to share link for promo site via Facebook and twitter, in facebook we got something like ["share dialog"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) or post bundle like

```
Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/feed", bundle, HttpMethod.POST, 
       new Request.Callback(){
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

but there are no twitter sdk for android(trully I use twitter4j) and no way to post bundle

so how to tweet link via twitter?

Answer (score 2):

If you send text with link like "Here is our link: http://stackoverflow.com" - twitter will understand it and get info from your link and show it - as I understand you need to see your recognized link in twitter feed.
To post link you can make intent like @Adrian Sicaru or create your own custom dialog using asynctask with twitter4j as you mention:

```
@Override
protected Bundle doInBackground(Bundle... params) {
    Bundle args = params[0];
    Bundle result = new Bundle();

    String paramMessage = args.getString(MESSAGE);
    String paramLink = args.getString(LINK);

    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey("your ConsumerKey");
    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("your ConsumerSecret");

    String accessToken = "your Token";
    String accessTokenSecret = "your Secret";

    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(builder.build());
    mTwitter = factory.getInstance(new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret));
    try {
        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(paramMessage);

        if (paramLink != null) {
            status = new StatusUpdate(paramMessage + " " + paramLink);
        }
        mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        result.putString(RESULT_ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via intent like this :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This will open a list with apps already installed that can answer the intent, like gmail, facebook and... twitter.

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Also, if you want to directly call twitter and don't want to choose, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596063/2377301)

Answer (score 1):

Like @TribblerWare answered just write link in tweet and twitter recognized it.

By the way, you can use [ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) for this - just authorize user and use **requestPostLink** with bundle as parameter

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle(); 
postParams.putString(SocialNetwork.BUNDLE_LINK, link); 
socialNetwork.requestPostLink(postParams, message, postingComplete);
```

more detailed you can see in [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815900/Android-social-network-integration)