# Open and close 3rd party app within my app in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I know it is impossible to close a running 3rd party app.
But what if i opened the 3rd party app within my app? Is there a way to close/finish it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but the user should have that app installed on his device. see following links

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

[Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
             int processid = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
       {
           ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
           if(info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("here your package name")){
              processid = info.pid;
           } 
       }
android.os.Process.killProcess(processid);
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: I know how to open an installed app with an intent. All i want is just to close it again.

Comment: you can not do it as it is not available within same Context.

Comment: if you run some thing in service you can try android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.processid); but for that you need to have processid