# Open android application by click on website button?

Tags: java, android

I have android application which contain html webpage with one single button. The html file is placed into the asset folder in android. I open html file into the webview. Now, i what want to open the another application which is install in android device by click on the html page button.

Can you please anyone help me how i will do that and also give me the some reference from where i will get some help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent or try this `Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);`

Comment: This is work for me 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/3758898

Answer (score 2):

I think @Sk Maniruddin is asking how to open another app from a webpage. And the solution to that is using an intent, as the link.

```
  <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

for more information you can look at the doc:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#example

Comment: Yes, I am asking this. But using this link the app is not open.

Comment: Hum.. it works for me. Are you using something like `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` to force the new link open in the same page?

Comment: I am use like that you have mention.

Comment: oh.. then you should disable/delete it, otherwise this would not work.

Comment: I don't think you need anything. not even the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` if you are using a local file

Comment: <a href="intent://shealth_host/#Intent;scheme=http;action=com.samsung.android.healthapp;end">Click Me</a>  write in html file.

Comment: <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.samsung.android.healthapp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="shealth_host"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>  Write in manifest file. Is there any think wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly  set your onclik method of button in html like this.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_id" onclick="click.performClick();" />
```

enable javascript your webview

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

after that you can detect this click by this code:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void performClick() {// detected click 
                Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.This, DestinationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

            }

        }, "click");
```

Comment: interesting. I used this method on my 2 projects and it was work.
Are you sure to make evrything correctly? Did you notice the name that before  ?.performClick(); must be same with the end of the addJavascriptInterface method's parameter?

Comment: webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
  webview.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
   @JavascriptInterface
   public void performClick() {// detected click 
    //                Intent i = new Intent(FromActivity.This, DestinationActivity.class);
    //                    startActivity(i);
    Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

  }, "click"); 

I write the above code.

Comment: Did you set click method of button in html like this?
onclick="click.performClick();"

Comment: Yes. I use same method.

Comment: 03-17 02:23:16.901: I/chromium(16994): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (12)

I got message like above.

Comment: Can you try webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

Comment: I throw in the towel :) I hope you will find the solution. Have a nice day.