# Display a PDF file received via POST response / download on Android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

The android app I am working on consists of a webview.

On click of one of the links in the webview, an AJAX POST request is made to receive a PDF file.

[image: Response Header]

At the moment, on clicking the pdf download link (on the webview), no pdf file is downloaded.

I tried to intercept the request by WebResourceResponse shouldIntercpetRequest(), but couldnt access the response header / pdf data.

**What approach must be taken to display the pdf on an android device, received via the above method ?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> **What approach must be taken to display the pdf on an android device, received via the above method ?**

Assuming that you already have the PDF data with you, Intent can be used to launch the PDF application which will use the PDF data.
See the following link for more:
[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)