# Android - start other app

Tags: android

I have a problem. I want to open file in other app from my app button.

In text input - name of file. I click button 'open'. File will be opened in other app (not default reader of file type from text input)

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate, please reference [this][1] stack post


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Are you trying this in your own app?

If not, go to Settings->Default Applications (depends on your device model) and clear defaults for your 'default reader' app. Then when you click the 'open' button, It will prompt you to select the application you want to open the file with (if you have compatible applications installed).

Comment: Yes, button in my app should open file in another app