# Launching app within another app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, launch, applinks

So I'm looking for the best way to open an app within another app on Xamarin forms when the app is install.. Currently I have an external link to the playstore (which loads up the app on play store) but, when the app is installed I'd like to link directly to this..
How would i go about doing this with Xamarin forms?  Cheers

Here's how I went about fixing this issue :

**Setting up app linking in Xamarin**

This is possible but we need to change the code to the app we are linking to.

**"App from" (in our case) changes :**

To link to another app the change made to the main app is minimal:
1)  Create a new URI.  E.g. (URI AppLink = new Uri("http://appto/load");)
2)  Set up the link with Device.OpenURI(AppLink);

**"App to" (in our case) changes :**

**Android**:

In main activity we need to add an intent filter, here is an example of what this looks like:
    [IntentFilter(new [] {Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        DataScheme="appto",
        DataHost="load",
        Categories=new [] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault })]

The DataScheme and DataHost correspond to the uri link above.

**iOS**:

Within the info.plist file in the advanced tab we need to create a new "url type"
I added an identifier of “com.appto.test” and URL scheme of “appto” (corresponds with uri link)
After these changes are done, the app should link. Atleast with the example it worked.

Comment: So you want to launch an application?

Comment: Yeah basically.. Click a button linking to another app, which should directly open#

Comment: Not entirely sure how you will do this cross platform, but the android way (easy to convert the java to c#) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: Cheers.. I supposeI can do this differently depending on the platform and use platform specific code

Comment: RobJakeDorsett, can you please post your code if possible. I am also looking for the same thing.

Comment: I can't post the code because it was client work - I'll explain how I did it, see edits