# Intents to link to another app

Tags: android

I have recently developed my second app. On clicking a specific button, I wish to open my first app. How do I do this?

I do know that I have to use Uri.parse, but how exactly do I use it?

Comment: Theres 2 ways to do that, they are called explicit and implicit intents, read about and choose what fits your needs. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596063/1764803

Comment: Yes, I know i need to use explicit intents. But how exactly do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create an intent for that.As you know the package name  you can create an intent as below and call startActivity

```
Intent launchIntent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SO question [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent.I) found the below answer good enough

```
 public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if (i == null) {
                return false;
                //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
            }
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open the other application you should know the package name of the launching app.
try below code .

```
try {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("pakage name of application which you want to launch");
    if (intent ! = null) {
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    context.startActivity(intent);
   }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```