# How to open current activity current application from my application Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, uri

I am developing new application which have print wireless feature. And I am using ePrint technology. PDF file which I generated before, I want to preview it directly using ePrint application (apk) like below screenshot :
[image]

I have URI for my pdf file, then I already decompiled ePrint application (apk), and found this one in its manifest. I am not sure, but I think below screenshot refers to preview activity.

[image]

So how can I open directly ePrint Preview activity from my application, and I have parameter URI file which I want to print ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596063/3839235

Comment: @william : how to preview directly my pdf file from my URI parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Following code might be solve your problem.

It will work only if you have `ACTION_PRINT` in your libraries.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/pdf_name.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("org.androidprinting.intent.ACTION_PRINT");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how to preview directly my pdf file from my URI parameter ?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=org.androidprinting.intent.ACTION_PRINT flg=0x10000000 }
 already used your code, and got this error :

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: open another application from my application, but directly to print preview activity