# Is it possible to launch an android/Iphone app through a web link?

Tags: android, html, iso

I am running a small digital mapping company that creates digital ski maps and my customers are forwarded to a payment success page that outlines how they install the map on their phone (this question assumes they are using the site on a mobile device). One of the steps happens to be "open such and such a app" on your phone.

Is it at all possible to have a link that when clicked, opens a specific app (that was already installed in an earlier step) on their mobile device, similar to when you have a weblink to android play store app?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response - I'm curious, that appears to do what I'm looking for, but written in an android development environment - how would you implement that in a web environment?

Answer (score 0):

iOS:

You need to know the apps URL scheme (if it has one). Then launch it by linking to the url, for example if the scheme was `youtube` you would open the link `youtube://` in a browser.

Android:

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)