# How to open an app from a different device

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is there a way to realize the following scenario?

App X on Device A (with Android) forces App Y on Device B (with Android) to open itself. The communication could happen in wifi or bluetooth or other kind of protocol.

Obviously, after a enrollment/binding phase between the two devices.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1- Using a background service on the device B, and using GCM send a message to the second device, than processing the request to open the app.

2- Using BT if you're using the two devices close from each other.

Answer (score 1):

yes.

Make the connection between devices (however you want to do it)

Tell app X to open app Y.

Device B receives the command and starts the intent to open the requested app.

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent/7596063#7596063)