# how to launch from one android app to another android app in xamarin.native.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my project I have a requirement where two separate team will be developing two separate xamarin.native.Android application(ex: app2 & app3), but at the end, we need to create a single application integrating both the applications(say app1). So in xamarin.Android is there any option to add app2 & app3 project as reference to app1 and from app1 to navigate to app2 or app3 pages or any similar solution to achieve this? (we are looking for this solution so that diff application team can work independently and integrate to a single application at the end).

Comment: Android's Intents might do what you want. You can use Intent filters and different things to launch specific activities in another app. There is some introductory information on this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent

Comment: Hi, You are right but intent filter works if the two application need to be deploy in the emulators then only it will works.In my case that is not. the (App 1, app2 & app 3) are just code not deployed in emulators. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: So you're building 3 separate apps, but the users will only install 1 of those apps? I was under the impression you would be installing all of them.

Comment: Is there any reason to even build them as separate apps instead of just building multiple Android class libraries and adding each library?

Comment: For example we have three apps(App1 ,App2 and App3). I will add reference app2 and app3 in app1 and install app1 in the emulator. in this case i need from app1 to app2/app3 how to navigation will be done.

Comment: That is what our requirement. Because App2 and App3 are doing two different teams. App1 we are doing based on some configuration we need to load their apps(App2/App3).

Comment: Will app2 or app3 ever be actually installed on a device? If not, it might make more sense to build them as class libraries. Otherwise, you can try just adding app2 and app3 as an assembly reference to app1. (Like you would any other assembly). It should work for the most part, at one time resources weren't loading, but that might be fixed.

Comment: App2 and App3 will not install in device. We are tried to add reference in App1. if we ran app1 is launched after that we are navigating app2. here what is happending the app2 UI is not update is still showing the app1 UI but the ctor is hitting app2 only.

Comment: i will tell you what we tried we added refernces in app1. we added one page(test.axml) in app2 but this page is not there in app1. if we ran app1 it is launched and do navigation we are getting an error(test.axml) file not found. Because this file is not there in app1. Still it is searching files in app1 only but ctor hitting app2.

Comment: Yeah I don't think resources will load between apps. I don't really know how to make that work. I'm not sure it's possible when using multiple apps. Hopefully someone here will know how. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Dylan for your support.