# Android studio - Allowing app to open when click the button

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a GUI using Android studio that contains 4 buttons and I want to open separate apps which already installed in my phone (Facebook, Twitter...) as they click on. I'm a novice in Android St. and can anyone help with my problem?

Comment: USE INTENT FOR THAT

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent/

Answer (score 2):

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.ImageButton01) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Application Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setClassName("com.xxx.your_package_name",
                    "com.xxx.your_class_name");

            startActivity(i);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
                ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("packagename", "packagename.Activity");
                intent.setComponent(comp);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Put this code in your onClick()

Comment: how to find packagename and packagename.Activity of installed app ?

Comment: You will have to do like this `final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
//list of installed apps.
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}`