# Intent to Open the Phone's Call History

Tags: android

I to display phone call history when a user clicks a button. Can this be done with an intent? Which intent should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made some minor edits. I changed the title of your question to better describe the underlying question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Intent` with action `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and type `CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE`;

**Try this:**

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentCallLog = new Intent();
            intentCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intentCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(intentCallLog);
        }
    });
```

Make sure you have added the permission `android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

> **READ_CALL_LOG**: Allows an application to read the user's call log.
>
> Note: If your app uses the READ_CONTACTS permission and both your
>   `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` values are set to `15` or `lower`, the
>   system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need
>   this permission, be sure your `targetSdkVersion` is `16` or `higher`.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CALL_LOG).

Hope this will help~