# How to open my app implicitly with my scheme?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have the app "A" the need to be opened from the others apps "B,C,D" by implicit intent

So, in my app "A" I have defined intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data
        android:host="applink"
        android:scheme="mobileapp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and in app "B" I have defined the implicit intent

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package.name.of.destination.app");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

And I get such error

```
2018-06-26 19:35:44.155 2270-2270/com.example.ezplan.deleteit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ezplan.deleteit, PID: 2270
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25883)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25883) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1666)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4584)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:792)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4542)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:779)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4903)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4871)
    at com.example.ezplan.deleteit.MainActivity.doOnCLickButton(MainActivity.java:29)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Or, just give me a sample how to do it correctly

Feel free to ask

**EDIT1**

1)my filter in the app that I need to open

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "mobileapp://applink” -->
            <data
                android:host="applink"
                android:scheme="mobileapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

2) My code in the app that try invoke external app

```
public void testit(View view)
{
    Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("mobileapp://applink"))
            .setPackage("package.name.of.destination.app");

    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
}
```

Exeption

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=mobileapp://applink pkg=package.name.of.destination.app }

Comment: Hi, try to set `launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);` or even better   try to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596063/3559908)

Comment: The exception doesn't look like it has anything to do with your `IntentFilter` at all.
Show us your `OnClickListener` and the `XML` layout as well. Are you using Data binding?

Comment: @Darwind added EDIT section in the question, no I don't use DataBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)) states:

> Returns a "good" intent to launch a front-door activity in a package. This is used, for example, to implement an "open" button when browsing through packages. The current implementation looks first for a main activity in the category `Intent.CATEGORY_INFO`, and next for a main activity in the category `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`. Returns `null` if neither are found.

If you don't comply to this contract, `LaunchIntent` is null and thus you crash.

Usually you have a main launcher intent filter defined in your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This would be found by `getLaunchIntentForPackage()`. Without changing or adding the intent filters, you've defined, you could also create the appropriate intent to match it manually:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("mobileapp://applink"))
                            .setPackage("package.name.of.destination.app");
```

Comment: added EDIT section in question

Comment: of course. Did you try this implementation? Is it work for you?

Comment: but I have checked this URI with Android St, at the top there is tab `app` I clicked on it then `EditConfiguration` and then in `Launch Options` I choose instead `Default Activity` -> `URL` with this filter param `mobileapp://applink` and my app was opened . Did you get my idea?

Comment: How did you define the application id within your gradle files? Have you tried the code without using the package?

Comment: yes, it is works:) thanks! But strange... there are 2 place where package defined 1 - is manifest, 2- is gradle. They are the same.

Comment: Historically the package defined in the manifest was the application id as well. With the gradle build system this changed and the application id can be defined explicitly or modified with a suffix like `.debug` for debug builds. The package is still used as package for `R` and `BuildConfig`.